# Not able to iterate twice in chunked dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

here i am able to iterate successfully in first one but second iteration is not executing at all. Can any one guide. Thanks in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
df= pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\abc.csv',chunksize=2, iterator=True)
for i in df:
    print('first iteration')
    print(i)

for i in df:
    print('second iteration')
    print(i.groupby('b').sum())
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior while reading a dataset in chunks.
If you want to iterate over this again, you can read the csv in chunks again:

```py
import pandas as pd
df= pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\abc.csv',chunksize=2, iterator=True)
for i in df:
    print('first iteration')
    print(i)

df= pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\abc.csv',chunksize=2, iterator=True)
for i in df:
    print('second iteration')
    print(i.groupby('b').sum())
```

Alternatively you can store your results in one iteration and process them later:

```py
import pandas as pd
df= pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\abc.csv',chunksize=2, iterator=True)
first_list = []
second_list = []
for i in df:
    # just once iterating over the TextFileReader and storing results you want
    # preferably filtering and keeping only the things you need to save memory
    first_list.append(i)
    second_list.append(i.groupby('b').sum())

# now you can iterate over the results you wanted as many times as you please:
for xx in first_list:
    print("in first iteration of first list")
    print(xx)
for xx in first_list:
    print("in second iteration of first list")
    print(xx)
for xx in first_list:
    print("in third iteration of first list")
    print(xx)

for yy in second_list:
    print("in first iteration of second list")
    print(yy)
```

The df you get from `df= pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\abc.csv',chunksize=2, iterator=True)` is a `pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader` and not a pandas dataframe that you can iterate over again and again.
Hence you have to treat is as if you will exhaust the items inside it on one pass and change your code accordingly.

Comment: @ranjit your upvotes and answer selection are appreciated!